# How to rename, No column name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I want to rename some columns but I am not getting these columns to rename. You can see in the image,I want to set the red tick value to index1 and for the green tick as index2 but I am not able to do because I am not getting these two columns for renaming?

[image: pandas]

Comment: they are indexes. Do `reset_index()` to get them as normal columns. Or use `rename_axis(index=['red_ticks', 'green_ticks'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referrring to a multi-index dataframe, the green tick column is index. You can use `.reset_index()` to get them as a column  named "index" and later rename it, or use `rename_axis(index=['red_ticks', 'green_ticks'])` or whatever name you like.